# li as select item using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown,0);
dropdownArray.forEach(function(el){
 var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
   menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
   arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

 button.onclick = function(event) {
  if(!menu.hasClass('show')) {
   menu.classList.add('show');
   menu.classList.remove('hide');
   arrow.classList.add('open');
   arrow.classList.remove('close');
   event.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
   menu.classList.remove('show');
   menu.classList.add('hide');
   arrow.classList.remove('open');
   arrow.classList.add('close');
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 };
})

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
    return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-weight: norma;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background: #2980B9;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
  background: #2c89c6;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
  content: '\25BC';
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  background: #EEE;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.dropdown .show,
.dropdown .hide {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Item <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">option 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Drop down works fine. But problem is as I want to use it instead of select tag, so I need to minimize the list field after I select a item. And a way that I can take the data as select item works.

*sorry for bad English.

Comment: it would be nice if you can delete some parts of the code so we don't need to read everything, because most of this code is not related with your question

Answer (score 0):

I really like your custom drop-down menu, especially the CSS you included to give some animation to your menu's expand/collapse actions. I've included a modified version of your snippet, and I hope you'll find it to be of help. I'll explain the revisions I made in what is to follow.

First off, let me begin by noting that I have some minor adjustments to the HTML content. In particular, I included an `<input>` field before the entire drop-down menu markup with a corresponding `<label>` element. This has been added to provide a quick manner of illustrating how to capture the value of a particular item from within the selection menu. Now, when you click on one of the drop-down menu's list items, that item's value will be inserted in said `<input>` field.

Next, you'll probably notice that I've added a few `class` or `id` attributes to some relevant HTML elements. This is largely as a matter of convenience and to make their selection (through the appropriate JavaScript selectors) easier. One important addition, however, are the `data-`attributes used on the `.dropdown-menu` unordered list element. It is a somewhat common pattern seen in normal `<select>` form inputs where one adds a `data-`attribute containing the value of each individual `<option>` element (similar to what is shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples)). I will address this briefly at a later point briefly. Though seemingly redundant, giving some `data-`attribute (or, alternatively, fixing the `value` attribute) to the content within the opening and closing tags provides an easy way of referencing that same value later without having to resort to the `innerHTML` method. For more on `data-attributes`, see this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_access).

---

The first thing to note is that I moved all my `var` declarations to the very top of the script. In your original snippet, you have three separate variable declarations/assignments within the body of a `forEach` loop:

```
dropdownArray.forEach(function(el) {
    var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
        menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
        arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');
    /* Some more code follows... */
  });
```

This is the first thing I'd point out that could be improved upon. Specifically, this is less than desirable because you are essentially reassigning the value of the `button`, `menu` and `arrow` variables in each iteration of the `forEach` loop. Since these are, instead, meant as constant references to fixed elements of the DOM, it's advisable to pull these out of the loop and, by extension, just group them alongside your two variables at the very top. You'll also notice that I have replaced the `var` keyword with the ES6 `const` keyword. While this does not change anything outright, I did so to emphasize that these are fixed (*i.e.*, `const`ant) references to elements of the DOM and may not be reassigned.

---

Next, you'll notice I wrote out a function, `clickHandler()`, that will be used as the callback function to an event listener that will follow. While it's perfectly fine to just write this function inline (*i.e.*, as an anonymous function and argument to the event listener), I have chosen to decouple it into its own space for clarity.

As you had originally done, I too used the `preventDefault()` method, here doing so as the first statement in the function's body.

Where you previously had 14 lines of code to add/remove the appropriate classes on the `menu` and `arrow` elements, I have only 4. It is quite simple to understand how you can condense this. First and foremost, there is no explicit need to divvy these class addition/removal actions into `if` and/or `else` blocks. Rather, you can simply make use of the [`toggle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) on the `classList` property of the [Element API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). For this to function correctly, however, it is necessary to seed the `menu` and `arrow` HTML elements with the CSS classes appropriate for the initial state: `.hide` and `.close`, respectively. You'll see this reflected in the HTML markup.

The last thing to be done with this function is to add an `if` conditional to check if the target of the user's click is, in fact, one of the drop-down menu's selection boxes (*i.e.*, the `<li>`s). This can be done in various ways, but perhaps the cleanest is achieved with the [`contains()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) on the `Node` API. To this end, I began by making a `let` declaration (again, ES6 syntax) for `targ` and assigned it to the DOM node upon which the user clicked. (I made a temporary variable to hold this node so that we wouldn't have to repeatedly refer to it as `evt.target` in the code that follows; this is, furthermore, a good practice and confers performance benefits, if only minor ones, because the JS engine does not have to repeatedly perform lookups but can, instead, refer to a fixed value held in state as a variable). I then specified by `if` condition, using here the aforementioned `contains()` method. The provided conditional expression evaluates the binary (`true` or `false`) assertion that `targ` is a descendant node (*read:* child element) of the `.dropdown-menu` unordered-list (given by the `menu` variable). In the event such is `true`, the value of the `<input>` element is assigned to be the value of the `data-optValue` attribute on the clicked `<li>` element.

```
 let targ = evt.target;
  if (menu.contains(targ)) {
    selectionInput.value = targ.dataset.optvalue;
  }
```

In the event the target is not a descendant node of `menu`, it stands to be reasoned that the user either did not click on an entry of the dropdown-menu or that it was the `button` element. NOTE: As an alternative to assigning the `<input>` field's value as the value contained in the custom `data-` attribute, one could also do as shown below:

```
if (evt.target !== selectMenu && evt.target !== button) {
  selectionInput.value = evt.target.innerHTML;
}
```

I would (at least from a personal point-of-view), discourage this, as it could complicate things should you, for example, add more HTML content nested within the individual `<li>` tags of the drop-down menu.

---

Finally, we conclude with adding a simple event handler. In this case, I've attached the click event to the `selectMenu` element (*i.e.*, the top-level `<ul`> tag) passing it the aforementioned `clickHandler()` function as a callback.

```js
const selectMenu = document.querySelector('#custom-select'),
      selectionInput = document.querySelector('#input-field'),
      dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown'),
      dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown,0),
      button = document.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
      menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
      arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

// Event callback function:
function clickHandler(evt) {  
  evt.preventDefault();
  menu.classList.toggle('show');
  menu.classList.toggle('hide');
  arrow.classList.toggle('open');
  arrow.classList.toggle('close');
  
  let targ = evt.target;
  if (menu.contains(targ)) {
    selectionInput.value = targ.dataset.optvalue;
  }
}

// 'Click' event registration:
selectMenu.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);



// Purely your code below:
Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font: normal 40px/1.4 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a { text-decoration: none; }
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background: #2980B9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 
                      0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  box-shadow:         0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover { background: #2c89c6; }
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-180deg);
  transform:         rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition:         transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(0);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(0);
  transform:         rotate(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition:         transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before { content: '\25BC'; }
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li { padding: 0; }
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  background: #EEE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 0 white inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  box-shadow:         0 1px 0 white inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.dropdown .show,
.dropdown .hide {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -moz-transform:    scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform:     scaleY(1);
  transform:         scaleY(1);
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation:    showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation:         showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <label for='input-field'>Selection:&nbsp;</label>
  <input type='text' id='input-field' value='' />
  <br /><br />
  
  <ul id='custom-select'>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Item
        <i class="icon-arrow close"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu hide">
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 1">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">Option 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @IsenrichO, thanks for details. It really helped me to understand then code. But problem is "Select Item" text is not replaced with selected option text. Is there any way to replace .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] text with option text?

Comment: Also your code doesn't work for multiple select box too.

Comment: @IsenrichO, I want to show all the menus that I have selected. How do I do this through the loop