# Vanilla Javascript custom select box for multiple field

Tags: javascript

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown,0);
dropdownArray.forEach(function(el){
  var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
      menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
      arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

  button.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!menu.hasClass('show')) {
      menu.classList.add('show');
      menu.classList.remove('hide');
      arrow.classList.add('open');
      arrow.classList.remove('close');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
      menu.classList.remove('show');
      menu.classList.add('hide');
      arrow.classList.remove('open');
      arrow.classList.add('close');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
})

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  float:left;
  margin-right:30px;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font: normal 40px/1.4 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a { text-decoration: none; }
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background: #2980B9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset,
    0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 
    0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  box-shadow:         0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset,
    0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover { background: #2c89c6; }
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-180deg);
  transform:         rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition:         transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(0);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(0);
  transform:         rotate(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition:         transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before { content: '\25BC'; }
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li { padding: 0; }
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  background: #EEE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset,
    0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 0 white inset,
    0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  box-shadow:         0 1px 0 white inset,
    0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.dropdown .show,
.dropdown .hide {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -moz-transform:    scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform:     scaleY(1);
  transform:         scaleY(1);
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation:    showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation:         showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type='text' id='input-field1' value='' />
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Item <i class="icon-arrow"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 1">option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">option Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">option Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">option Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input type='text' id='input-field2' value='' />
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Item <i class="icon-arrow"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 1">option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2">option Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3">option Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4">option Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to make a select box using `li` as select box but it doesn't work well in all browsers. I want to select an option and option value will be stored in a input box which we can make hidden using CSS. But the problem is how can I select an option from drop down list and store the value to the input box and also need to replace "Select Item" text with option text. And also need to work it on multiple field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [li as select item using vanilla Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829055/li-as-select-item-using-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: its not totally duplicate. My problem still not solved. Came another problem.

Comment: You got an extensive answer explaining lots of the details in your other question already. We expect you to show that you make something of that. It does not exactly what you want, it might need a few more tweaks here and there? Then go and _modify_ the code accordingly, using what new knowledge you gained from someone taking the time to write such a lengthy answer for you. If you are not willing or able to do that - then you are in the wrong place. StackOverflow is not a service where you just "order" what you need.

Comment: _"Came another problem"_ - well then describe that additional problem, _specifically_. What you did here is just dump your whole code again, with barely anything that would deserve the name "question".

Comment: I understand what you said, But here people help each other, so what is the problem if I need something better for the problem. If someone describe his code in thousand word that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: Well then give us a better problem _description_, first of all. What is the _specific_ issue, and what have _you_ tried to solve it so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add event listeners to the anchor element clicks and, in the handler, you need to change the value of their relevant input element. To do this, I recommend adding another attribute like `data-associated-input` which can tell your event handler code exactly which input element a particular input option should modify. The following is an example of those ideas implemented:

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown,0);
dropdownArray.forEach(function(el){
 var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
   menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-menu'),
   arrow = button.querySelector('i.icon-arrow');

 button.onclick = function(event) {
  if(!menu.hasClass('show')) {
   menu.classList.add('show');
   menu.classList.remove('hide');
   arrow.classList.add('open');
   arrow.classList.remove('close');
   event.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
   menu.classList.remove('show');
   menu.classList.add('hide');
   arrow.classList.remove('open');
   arrow.classList.add('close');
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 };
})

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
    return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};


function setupListeners(){
/* get all dropdown options */
var ulMenus = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
for(var i=0;i<ulMenus.length;i++){
 var opts = ulMenus[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
 for(var x=0; x<opts.length;x++){
  /* add listener */
  opts[x].setAttribute("onclick", "updateHidden(this);return !1;");
  opts[x].setAttribute("onClick", "updateHidden(this);return !1;"); /* Support old browser that don't recognize all lowercase html */
 }
}

}

function updateHidden(ele){

     if(!ele)
 return false;

     var eleHidden = document.getElementById(ele.getAttribute("data-associated-input"));
     if(eleHidden){
      eleHidden.value = ele.getAttribute("data-optvalue");
     }

}

setupListeners();
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  float:left;
  margin-right:30px;
}
.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font: normal 40px/1.4 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a { text-decoration: none; }
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background: #2980B9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 
                      0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  box-shadow:         0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover { background: #2c89c6; }
.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(-180deg);
  transform:         rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition:         transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(0);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(0);
  transform:         rotate(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.6s;
  transition:         transform 0.6s;
}
.dropdown .icon-arrow:before { content: '\25BC'; }
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li { padding: 0; }
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  background: #EEE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 0 white inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  box-shadow:         0 1px 0 white inset,
                      0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.dropdown .show,
.dropdown .hide {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  -moz-transform:    scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform:     scaleY(1);
  transform:         scaleY(1);
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation:    showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation:         showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type='text' id='input-field2' value='' />
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Item <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 1" data-associated-input="input-field2">option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 2" data-associated-input="input-field2">option Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 3" data-associated-input="input-field2">option Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-optValue="Option 4" data-associated-input="input-field2">option Four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer Doak for reply, but did it on some other way, Not working this code I think. Conflicts with multiple fields.